# How to choose columns as index

Tags: database, indexing

When creating index for a table, what's the rules we should observe?
To make my question in more detail:
1. In my understanding, to the simplest, we choose a column from a table as index, then sorting the selected column, saving them on disk together with an address in the original complete table. When we do query using where clause, if the column happens to be in the where clause, by search the sorted index, we quickly got the complet record entry. On the other hand, if the where clause didn't contains the indexed column, the index offers no help to the query. Is that right?
2. If we use multiple columns as index, the db engine may save several copies on each individual column, and select the correct one according to where-clause?
3. If I choose multiple columns as an index, do we need to consider the sequence of the columns?

Comment: quite common is: Index columns that are used a lot in where clauses or sorts, such as a state or date column...but really...this is so easy to get a GOOD answer from google.

Comment: No it doesn't matter!

Answer (score 0):

Since adding index to a column has workload, you should have a logical reason to do that. For example if you have a table for saving players and you always want to sort and search them by their height, it's a good idea to add index on height column